# How to convert UNIX timestamp to date using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js, unix-timestamp

I am using chart.js to display "price" data over the past 30 days. I am using a price API to do so. However the .time parameter returns the time as a UNIX timestamp. I would like the time to be displayed as a readable date.

To get the time and prices:

```
const data = json.Data.Data
const times = data.map(obj => obj.time)
const prices = data.map(obj => obj.high)
return {
    times,
    prices
}
```

My chart.js labels:

```
labels: times,
```

Is there a way to return this data as a full date instead of a timestamp ?

Comment: Yes this is possible, you can take a look in the documentation for how to do it: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

Comment: I get this error when I try to change the time display format: chart.js@2.8.0:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

So I found a solution to this and it was to use moment.js.
link to reference: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

Solution:

```
(`MY API LINK=${moment(new Date()).subtract(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')}&end=${moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`)
```

Comment: Thats a *very* innefficient way to convert values and the maths looks decidedly odd - consider `new Date(unixtimestamp*1000);`